Laravel faking Http responses with different data in one test
I am struggeling Http::fake(). I have a test where I have to change the response body after the first faked API call, but it seems this is not possible.
Http::fake([
            'https://my.apicall.com/api/v1/Invoice/Factory/saveInvoice' => Http::response($invoiceBody, 201),
        ]);

// some code executed

Http::fake([
            'https://my.apicall.com/api/v1/Invoice/Factory/saveInvoice' => Http::response($invoiceBody2, 201),
        ]);

// more code executed

the second Http::fake() gets ignored, i receive the first body.
Any ideas?

You can use sequence instead of define fake response multiple times. Something like this
Http::fake([
    'https://my.apicall.com/api/v1/Invoice/Factory/saveInvoice' => Http::sequence()
        ->push($invoiceBody, 201)
        ->push($invoiceBody2, 201),
]);

// Your code


thank you ... I was so fixed on "why does this not work" that I did not see that point in the docs ...
